# Microsoft Outlook will not re-add my email account

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

I have previously had two e-mail addresses on my Microsoft Outlook.

Last Friday a fault, from what I later learnt later was a problem at 1and1 (my email provider) was encountered on my alternative account so I took this address off Outlook, just leaving my main account on Outlook.

The problem at 1and1 was rectified but for 2 days now I have been trying to put my alternative account back on Outlook to no avail.

I am inputting the correct data (imap.1and1.co.uk and auth.smtp.1and1.co.uk) as I can successfully send and receive the test message.

I go to the next stage and always get `the requested operation failed`.

Got in touch with BT my ISP and after exhaustive tests could not find anything wrong with Outlook.  They just tell me `For some unknown reason your address cannot be verified`.

As I said previously your address worked perfectly well on Outlook prior to last Friday.

I am desperate to get this account back on Outlook

Answer (score 0):

Instead of re-adding the account to your current Outlook profile, you should try creating a new profile. It doesn't take long, and may resolve your problem quickly. If it works, just set your new profile to be your default profile, then delete the faulty one.